# Permission Denied when trying to run Shell Script (containing Python sub-script)

Tags: python, linux, shell, permissions, raspberry-pi

I'm currently creating a Raspberry Pi (Model B) based temperature sensor with a display. I am trying to run a shell start up script in the LX Terminal but keep getting a "Permission Denied" error next to a Python sub-script as follows:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo /home/pi/tempsense/etc/init.d/envmon start
Starting envmon
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ /home/pi/tempsense/etc/init.d/envmon: 15:/home/pi/tempsense/etc/init.d/envmon: home/pi/tempsense/opt/envmon/displayenvmon.py: Permission denied
```

The shell script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          envmon
# Required-Start:    $local_fs
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start/stop envmon
### END INIT INFO

case "$1" in
  start)
    /home/pi/tempsense/opt/envmon/dht11 &
    echo "Starting envmon"
    /home/pi/tempsense/opt/envmon/displayenvmon.py &
    ;;
  stop)
    pkill dht11
    pkill displayenvmon
    echo "envmon stopped"
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /home/pi/tempsense/etc/init.d/envmon {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

The Python script causing the Permission denied errors is:

```
#!/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
from RPLCD import CharLCD
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import subprocess, re
import time

# Data file - current reading
datfile = "/var/envmon.data"

# Rate at which the LCD is updated
UPDATE_RATE = 5


lcd = CharLCD(cols=16, rows=2, 
        pin_rw=None,
        pin_rs=7,
        pin_e=8,
        pins_data=[25,24,23,18],
        numbering_mode=GPIO.BCM)


lcd.cursor_pos = (0, 0)
lcd.write_string('Visit @UWS_Pi')
lcd.cursor_pos = (1, 0)
lcd.write_string('TEMP & HUMID')
time.sleep(5);


# Get IP address - looks for first IP address which is not 127.0.0.1
address_string = subprocess.getoutput("ip addr")
ipaddr = "Unknown"

# Reg exp to extract IP addresss
search_inet = re.compile('inet (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})')  

for line in address_string.split('\n') :

    match = search_inet.search(line)
    if (match != None) :

        if (match.group(1) != '127.0.0.1') : 
            ipaddr = match.group(1)
            break

# Print the IP address to the LCD
lcd.cursor_pos = (1,0)
lcd.write_string (ipaddr)

# Sleep to give chance to read IP address   
time.sleep(5) 

# Loop get most recent reading and display on screen
while (True):

    fh = open (datfile, "r")
    entry = fh.read()

    # split into separate entries
    [currtime, currtemp, currhumid] = entry.split()

    # Change currtime to a formatted time ready for displaying
    formattime = time.strftime ("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", time.localtime(int(currtime)))
    # print time to display
    lcd.cursor_pos = (0,0)
    lcd.write_string (formattime)

    # Print temp and humidity values
    lcd.cursor_pos = (1,0)
    lcd.write_string ("T " + currtemp + "C  RH " + currhumid + "%   ") 

    time.sleep(UPDATE_RATE)
```

I am new to this and any helpful advice is appreciated.

Comment: Does that python script have the executable bit set?

Comment: I had tried chmod 777 if that helps @EtanReisner

Comment: Is `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` actually the path to the python binary?

Comment: Not the directory with the binary in it but *actually* the binary itself?

Comment: I'm new to this sorry; how would I check that mate? @EtanReisner

Comment: I'm assuming that to run python you run `python` in your shell and not `dist-packages`, right? What does `command -v python` say? I'm going to assume it says `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python` or something like that. You need **that** path in the shebang `#!` line.

Comment: It says `/usr/bin/python` @EtanReisner

Comment: Then assuming that's the python you need that's the path you need in your script. Where did that `/usr/local/...` path come from?

Comment: It was included in the Python code I obtained from an Opt directory I found online @EtanReisner

Answer (score 1):

To use the GPIO pins, the Python script needs to be run with administrator privileges. Either execute the shell script as root or call your Python script using sudo from within the shell script.

Answer (score 0):

Either log in as root, or run the program with sudo, because usually permission denied means you need root permissions, sudo runs that specific program with root permissions if you don't want to log in as root.